# public static final FirebaseFirestoreException.Code INTERNAL an internal error occured

Tags: android, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I'm having this error while trying to fetch data from firestore with a range filter whose lower and upper limits are specified but when I use one of the limits i.e (whereLessThan  or the other one whereGreaterThan) it works properly.

Could you please help me find source of this error? I have searched through firebase docs and only found this:

> Internal errors. Means some invariants expected by underlying system
>   has been broken. If you see one of these errors, something is very
>   broken.

Note1: This error has appeared after I cache cleared the app data, before that it was working well.

Note2: I don't know why but after I cache cleared app data, I started to receive error logs including link redirecting me to firestoreIndex to setup the indexes for complex querys that has range filters and orderby filter ,which seems weird why didn't i receive such logs before and why the database was just working perfect although no indexes were setup ?

Note3: Now, I have setup all the indexes required for each query but I still have this error.

Comment: Please add the code where you are getting this error.

Comment: @Robotec, did you get a solution for this, I'm also facing a similar issue.

Comment: I don't recall this issue, but i think sometimes you may need to restart your phone you're testing on or shout out simulator and restart it ,it helps me resolve some issues .If it persists ,keep my posted.